# AWS: What is the difference between s3:ResourceAccount AND aws:PrincipalAccount?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I was doing some reading about usage of VPC Interface Endpoints vs VPC Gateway Endpoints and came across the official AWS docs which had this section on how to control access from either of these to specific accounts. It looks like in order to restrict the use to a specific account S3 uses `s3:ResourceAccount` tag while other services use `aws:PrincipalAccount` tag. Given this:

**For Interface EP**

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "Policy1415115909152",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Access-to-bucket-in-specific-account-only",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotEquals": {
          "s3:ResourceAccount": "111122223333"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**For Gateway EP**

```
{
  "Sid": "AllowAccessFromAccount",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Principal": "*",
  "Action": "*",
  "Resource": "*",
  "Condition": {
    "StringEquals": {
      "aws:PrincipalAccount": "111122223333"
    }
  }
```

I get that these tags prefixs `s3:ResourceAccount` are specific for S3 types, but why need a dedicated tag such as this? Why can we not reuse `aws:PrincipalAccount`? and can we use the latter instead of the former for s3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two conditions have different purposes.

`aws:PrincipalAccount` is used to grant or restrict access based on the account which the principal in the request belongs to. So it looks at the incoming request and determines whether the principal is allowed or not.

`s3:ResourceAccount` on the other hand can be used to grant or restrict access to all buckets which belong in a certain account, regardless of which principal the request is coming from. So it looks at the incoming request and determines whether the requested S3 bucket is in an allowed account.

The two are not mutually exclusive and can indeed be used together as shown in an example in this blog: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/limit-access-to-amazon-s3-buckets-owned-by-specific-aws-accounts/